# Blue flashes in rum during fermentation

Tags: biochemistry, home-experiment, food-chemistry

While fermenting my rum wort (what rum is called before it is distilled) in a plastic fermentation barrel, I noticed little blue flashes appearing over the surface of the liquid. Any idea what could have caused this? I have looked around and the closest thing I could find is [triboluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboluminescence), but that doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: When you say "flash," are you saying that you can observe this in the dark?

Comment: A photo would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some microorganisms produce light, which is called bioluminescence.

Comment: Another thought - maybe you have created artificial will-o'-the-wisps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will-o%27-the-wisp#Attempted_scientific_explanations

Comment: A most interesting observation :). You generally need quite a lot of energy to cause something to glow, far more than normal thermal energy. Is it possible that static from the plastic bottle has something to do with it plus alcohol vapour?